# Rails: rails_admin extending action new of specified model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin for back-end. I wonder if there is any way to extend the "new" action of rails_admin to automatically assign current_user id to a specified model? Customizing the field doesn't seems to work for me since I dont want a hidden field.

Would anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to-set-default-values

I think this should do it. Try something like this in your configuration file.

```
config.model Post do 
  new do 
    field :user_id, :hidden do
      default_value do
        bindings[:view]._current_user.id
      end
    end
  end 
end
```